# remove comma separation from the specific number from JS

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting

I want to remove comma separation from the specific number but i want decimal places and i wrote a regular expression for that, when i pass a number with decimal places it is ok.

```
var num = '12,312,313,214,214,324.89';

num.replace(/,(?=.*\.\d+)/g, '');
```

> result = 12312313214214324.89

But when i pass

```
var num = '12,312,313,214,214,324';
```

without decimal it returns

> result = 12

Is there a way to remove commas in both the ways ?
 or any corrections in regular expression?

Comment: Have your tried `parseFloat()`?

Comment: @CodeLover yes. i think that is the reason. best answer thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simplify the regular expression:

`num.replace(/,/g, '')`

Answer (score 2):

Replace the regex in the replace method with `/,/g` which means matches the character,literally (case sensitive)

```js
var num = '12,312,313,214,214,324.89';
var num2 = '12,312,313,214,214,324';

function replaceComma(num) {
  return num.replace(/,/g, '');
};
console.log(replaceComma(num));
console.log(replaceComma(num2));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var num = '12,312,313,214,214,324.89';
var num_array = num.split(',');
var num_string = num_array.join('');
alert(num_string);
```

Comment: smart way, nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make a simple replace `num.replace(/,/g,'')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`var num="12,312,313,214,214,324";
num = num.replace(/^[, ]+|[, ]+$|[, ]+/g, "");
alert(num);`

Answer (score 0):

You should store the output value in variable so you can accessible for further operation.

```
var num = '12,312,313,214,214,324.89';
num = num.replace(/,/g, '');
console.log(num);
```